# Making a Color Toast in Android

Tags: android, toast, textcolor, android-toast

I have seen sometimes a Blue toast showing up when i connect my Samsung phone with wifi network. Can anyone help for customising the colour of the toast.

For example:

[image]

Comment: as in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html - making a custom toast

Comment: You make custom layout and set it to Toast.

Comment: @user2310289 - I have checked it out there, but didn't found anything regarding colour of toast

Comment: @MD - Can you please elaborate some more

Answer (score 1):

Like this way:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = youractivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast,
                    null);
            TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.tvtoast);
            text.setText("No Internet Connection");
            text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            Toast toast = new Toast(getActivity());
            toast.setView(layout);
            toast.setDuration(100);
            toast.show();
```

Make your own layout `custom_toast.xml` and set `Color` to `TextView` Text as per your need

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try This:-

```
SpannableString text = new SpannableString("Please Wait !!!!! ");  


        text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, 41, 0);  
        Toast.makeText(c.getApplicationContext(),text , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Another Way:-
Make an xml / customToast.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/toast_layout"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:padding="8dp"
              android:background="#DAAA"
              >
    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/img1"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
               />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textColor="#FFF"
              />
</LinearLayout>
```

In Activity:-

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customToast,
                               (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout));

TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText("This is a custom toast");

Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setView(layout);
toast.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom Toast view to suit your requirements. See the section titled "Creating a Custom Toast View" at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html