# Custom Toast View with default background

Tags: android

I have a custom Toast View:

XML code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/toast_layout_root"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:padding="8dp"
   android:background="#DAAA"
   >
<TextView android:id="@+id/text"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textColor="#ffa500"
   />
</LinearLayout>
```

Java code:

```
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout,(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));
TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText("custom toast");
Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setView(layout);
    toast.show();
```

I want to use `toast view` with default background and my font color.

[image: toast comparison]

Comment: I added a picture. I want to use custom toast view with default background.

Comment: the second parameter of inflate should be null

Comment: @ross what is your issue then?

Comment: @ross go to my this answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21899722/making-a-color-toast-in-android/21899823#21899823](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21899722/making-a-color-toast-in-android/21899823#21899823)